# Will using java stream for filtering out large sets of data cause a performance decrease?

Tags: java, list, java-stream

Assume I have hundreds of thousands of data to process.

And my class looks like

```
public class Group
{
   String id;
   String name;
}
```

And a list of these groups.

```
List<Group> groups = new Arraylist<>();
```

I want to make sure that I don't have any groups in this list without a name.

So I can think of two approaches

1. When I am looping through the data, I can decide whether or not to put it in this list to begin with
2. I can just keep the code simple until I need to filter out the list at the very end.

Option 2 would be something like this:

```
groups.stream.filter(g -> !StringUtils.isBlank(g.name)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there a preferred way of doing this? Pros and cons? Option 2 will make my code look much cleaner, however I'm worried because the dataset can be quite large and traversing through a large list may be a performance downgrade..

Answer (score 0):

*My opinion:*
I would recommend #1, so you don't waste memory on irrelevant data.
That it also performs better is nice too.

But only because you're talking about "quite large" ("hundreds of thousands"). For small lists, code clarity might be more desirable. If list can be small or large, code for large, otherwise memory overload and/or performance might kill/freeze the application.

Answer (score 0):

Java (and modern CPUs) are [more optimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373242/when-is-java-loop-predication-optimization-triggered-by-the-c2-jit-compiler) to deal with arrays rather than with random access data sets like trees, so iteration over the array is faster.
Moreover, ArrayList seems to be the [most effective structure](https://dzone.com/articles/preventing-your-java-collections-from-wasting-memo) among Java Collection API